# Adjust picture size within SharePoint 2010 Picture Library Slideshow Webpart?

Tags: sharepoint-2010

I am trying to implement an "out of the box" webpart that is with SharePoint 2010.

The "Picture Library Slideshow" webpart works great for what we need, however it reduces the size of the images being selected and leaves lots of whitespace around them.

I've been searching online for a fix, but most responses seem to point to 3rd party or custom jQuery ones to replace.

We're trying to avoid that, and just play with the code from the slideshow that is already included.

Any suggestions would be much appreciated!  Thank you in advance.

Comment: After much research, we broke down and enlarged the images in the library, actually worked out just fine inside the webpart.  Thanks for all who viewed this and pondered on a fix!

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately it is not supported to configure web part using out-the-box capabilities only what image type (original, web or thumbnail) to display in `Picture Library Slideshow  Web Part`, but you could try to customize the rendering of slideshow using the following client side approach.

The solution described below allows to display original (full-sized) images  in Picture Library Slideshow web part by overriding Slideshow control `ShowPic` function.

Step 1. Insert the `Content Editor` web part on the page where  `Picture Library Slideshow` web part resides.

Step 2. Inset the following JavaScript code into `Script Editor` web part:

```
<script type="text/javascript">


function SlideshowObjectInitializer() {

  ShowPic = (function(ShowPicOrig) {
      return function() {

           var ssObj = arguments[0];  //SlideShow object
           var curPicIdx=ssObj.index; //current picture index

           ShowPicOrig.apply(this, arguments); //call original ShowPic

           //apply some changes to display original picture in SlideShow control
           ssObj.image.src = ssObj.linkArray[curPicIdx]; //display original image instead of web image
           //change picture & container size to auto instead of fixed (by default web image size is used)
             ssObj.image.setAttribute('height','100%'); 
             ssObj.image.setAttribute('width','100%'); 
             var cell = ssObj.cell; 
             cell.style.width = 'auto';
             cell.style.height = 'auto';
             cell.style.display = '';
             var pcell = ssObj.cell.parentNode; 
           pcell.style.width = 'auto';
             pcell.style.height = 'auto';
      };
  })(ShowPic);

}  


ExecuteOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded(SlideshowObjectInitializer, 'imglib.js');
</script>
```

The specified code customizes SlideShow control to display original (full-sized) images from Picture library.

> It has been tested in SharePoint 2010/2013.

For more details about customizing Slideshow web part please follow [this blog post](http://vgrem.wordpress.com/2013/04/27/beyond-the-slideshow-web-part-capabilities-in-sharepoint-2010/)

Comment: Hi this method shows the small image first and then quickly changes it to bigger image. Can you please tell me how can I avoid that?